# Adding a layout dynamically into a Scrollview

Tags: android

This question seems to have been asked a dozen times already bu I haven't been able to deduce the solution from them.

I have a layout called `tile.xml` that looks like this:

```
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginLeft="50dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
    android:text="May Fong Robinson"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
    android:textStyle="bold" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginLeft="50dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
    android:text="Beautiful star-shaped spillway, Kechut Reservoir, Jermuk, Armenia"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />
```

I need to add this one of my views called `feed.xml` which I've declared as a `ScrollView` because I want to have multiple objects in it so I can vertically scroll though them. Here's my `feed.xml` file:

```
<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/scrollView1"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:background="#F1F1F1"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent" >

</ScrollView>
```

I'd like to dynamically add my "tile" from `tile.xml` to my "feed" `feed.xml` view while changing the text of the `TextViews` on the fly.

How can I do this? Thanks

---

The new `feed.xml`:

```
<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:background="#F1F1F1" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/tiles"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" >
    </LinearLayout>

</ScrollView>
```

...and the new `tile.xml`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
    android:background="#FFFFFF"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginLeft="50dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:text="May Fong Robinson"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
        android:textStyle="bold" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginLeft="50dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:text="Beautiful star-shaped spillway, Kechut Reservoir, Jermuk, Armenia"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: one thing you should know that `ScrollView` can add only one View in it. if you want to add multiple View then use some `layouts` e.g. `LinearLayout` and add view in it and then in the end add this LinearLayout in the `ScrollView`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First of all, add the 2 TextViews inside a layout.

then, in your code, where you want to dynamically add the TextViews you do the following :

```
ScrollView scroll = (ScrollView) findViewById(R.id.scrollView1);
LayoutInflater inflater =  (LayoutInflater)getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.tile, null);
scroll.addView(view);
```

To access the TextViews you have to do the following :

```
TextView textView1 = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.textView1);
textView1.setText("");
```

Also make sure to give your TextViews different IDs in the XML file. Currently they are both textView1

Comment: HI Eddy. That sort of worked for me. I added a `LinerLayout` to the `ScrollView` and I also added the two `TextViews` inside a `LinearLayout`. I then added the `LinearLayout` (contianing the `TextViews`) to the other `LinearLayout` (which was nested in the `ScrollView`). It now seems to add it dynamically. The second part of my question: how can I modify the text in the `TextView`s when adding it dynamically? Thanks

Comment: I had to modify `ScrollView scroll = (ScrollView) findViewById(R.id.scrollView1);` to `LinearLayout scroll = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.tiles);`

Answer (score 1):

ScrollView can only have 1 child, meaning the current structure of your "tile" layout can't be added to the ScrollView.
What you need is to add another Layout, let's say LinearLayout to your ScrollView so that it would be the ScrollView's only direct child. To this LinearLayout you can add as many childs as you want.
This can be done by using the LayoutInflater which you've probably encountered in numerous examples.

Answer (score 0):

```
**TRY THIS**
<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:background="#F1F1F1" >

<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/tiles"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

   <include layout="@layout/tile" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: That's not adding dynamically.